# FileLoadException on 'Microsoft.Owin'

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, fileloadexception

So I have installed SignalR through Nuget and it is depending on `Microsoft.Owin` which it then installed. Whenever I run my application it throws a `FileLoadException` in the Startup.cs om the `app.MapSignalR();` line. It says "File or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. The manifest definition of the found assembly do not match the reference of the assembly."

I am sure it includes the `Microsoft.Owin.dll` but when I try to reinstall it through Nuget it says it could not reinstall the Microsoft.Owin.XML

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of SignalR relies on Microsoft.Owin 2.0.2.0, not 2.0.1.0. See the following tutorial- you'll want to add Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost in the package manager, not Microsoft.Owin.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

Comment: That did in fact not solve anything as it does the exact same thing when calling `app.MapSignalR();`. The only difference is that it is now `Microsoft.Owin.Security` instead of just `Microsoft.Owin`...

Comment: It was because that it aimed at a higher version than it was set to redirect in the app.config

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes packages refer to specific versions of other packages. You can try to add a binding redirect for `Microsoft.Owin` in your `web.config` file (in the `<runtime>` section):

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This tells everything that references an older version than `2.1.0.0` to use `2.1.0.0` instead.

Comment: That was in fact already added to the `web.config` by the Nuget manager. So this did not solve anything.